# How to create Windows event log with Python

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, event-log

I have an issue with writing event log to Windows Event Viewer. I want to register a custom Event Log under `Applications and Services Logs` menu but I have no idea to do it in Python (I am using PyWin32 in this case). Basically we can register a custom log with Powershell's `New-EventLog` but I want to do it in Python.

These are some attemps I have done:

- Create an event log with Powershell's `New-EventLog`:

`New-EventLog -LogName <Log Name> -Source <Source>`

- In Python, open a handler with registered Log Name:

```py
import win32evtlog

hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(None, 'CustomRegisteredEventLog')
# then write to Event Log
win32evtlog.ReportEvent(hand, win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 0, None, ['some message'], None)
```

Those steps above actually works, the log is successfully submitted to event log, but I still need to register the Event Log with Python. Could anyone guide me on how to do this on Python?

Answer (score 1):

I post the full code of my current understanding of this for you below.

```
import win32evtlogutil
import win32evtlog
import sys

print("Python {0} on {1}".format(sys.version,sys.platform))

variable = ["x,","y","z"]


App_Name = "Python test"
App_Event_ID = 10001
App_Event_Category = 90
#App_Event_Type = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE
App_Event_Str = ["scanned: {}".format(var) for var in variable]
App_Event_Data= b"xyz"

'''

win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(ApplicationName, EventID, EventCategory,EventType,Inserts, Data, SID)

'''


win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent(App_Name,App_Event_ID, eventCategory= App_Event_Category,
                                eventType=win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                                strings=App_Event_Str,data=App_Event_Data)
```